# Route interprets JSON request as HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mime-types

Using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.2.12.

I am experiencing an issue when testing URLs with a ".json" extension. I'm building custom error pages and have the following:

```
# errors_controller.rb
def show
  @exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => { :error => @exception.message, :status => request.path[1..-1] } } 
    format.html { render :file => File.join(Rails.root, 'public', request.path[1..-1]), :format => [:html], :status => request.path[1..-1], :layout => false } 
  end
end

# routes.rb
match ":status" => "errors#show", :constraints => { :status => /\d{3}/ }

# application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

For URLs such as "localhost:3000/session/nourl.json", I trigger the HTML block of `respond_to`, and I can verify that the server responds with the HTML format with these logs:

```
Processing by ErrorsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"status"=>"404"}
Rendered public/404.html (13.2ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 48ms (Views: 47.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The only way I've been able to trigger the JSON block is with `:format => :json` in the route, then it works fine but "localhost:3000/session/nourl" would respond with JSON too.

It feels like I am doing something foolish here because I've seen other examples of both cases being triggered in the expected way and I see absolutely no other cases of similar behavior, so I'm compelled to think this is an isolated situation or it's some cascading issue that I cannot observe or am causing elsewhere.

If anyone could provide some insight on potential issues I would be appreciative.

Updated:

A little more info: If I query something like "localhost:3000/locations/1.json", I get the expected response; a JSON formatted page with the object details. I can't achieve this same behavior when requesting arbitrary URLs with a ".json" extension and attempting to format a custom JSON response to return. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sending headers along with your JSON request to tell the controller that the incoming request is `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Need more info.  Please post all the routes for your errors controller.

Comment: @CoolTapes- What info specifically? The route given is the only one I currently need as it is dynamically displaying the page based upon the request.path status code.

Comment: @CDub- Is there a reason that content-type isn't set to application/json when I specify the request format in the url?

Comment: go here http://phillipridlen.com/notes/2012/12/13/returning-multiple-formats-with-custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-rails/ read "Responding to multiple formats"

Comment: @phoet Looks like this is what I needed. If you'd like to put a few words about reading env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] =~ /\.json$/ as an answer I will mark it. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails delegates the call to the Error-Application where all the request-format stuff gets lost. So you will need to check that on your own. You could check on the request information like this:

```
  def api_request?
    env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] =~ /^\/api/
  end

  def json_request?
    env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] =~ /\.json$/
  end
```

Read more about this approach here: http://phillipridlen.com/notes/2012/12/13/returning-multiple-formats-with-custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-rails/